# QGIS: How to resize a group of polygons?

Tags: qgis

I was drawing polygons in the wrong CRS so I set layer CRS to the correct one. My polygons moved to another location and also changed the scale. I was able to move them to the correct location, but I can not find a solution on how to resize them (with keeping the distances between them). I do not remember in which CRS I was originally drawing them.

Comment: Don't ever set the CRS of a layer, unless you know exactly what you're doing. That being said: Which is your default CRS when creating a layer? A specific CRS, the project CRS, or EPSG4326? If you can't figure that out, you need to redraw your polygons in the correct CRS.

Answer (score 0):

The default CRS that QGIS will use if you don't specify one is 4326. Try changing to that and reprojecting.

Comment: I tried that, but it unfortunately did not work.

Comment: You could also try using the "Find Projection" tool. Zoom into the area of the map where the polygons should be and use "Map Canvas Extent" where it calls for the Target Area of Layer.

Comment: Thank you, but it was still not the right solution.